# Bootstrap collapse ie9 toggling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

This is driving me nuts.  I am sure it's something easy, but I just can't see it.

I am trying to use twitter bootstrap to open/close a form.  Of course, works fine on chrome, but not IE9.  I create a simple js fiddle that works in both:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id='s'> this works </div>
    <button id='b'>toggle</button>

</div>
$(document).ready(->
$('#s').collapse(toggle: true)

$('#b').click(-> 
  $('#s').collapse('toggle')
)
)
```

However, when I do (what looks to be exactly the same) in my app, it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(->

$('#phone_call_form').collapse(toggle: true )
$('#addPhone').click(->
  $('#phone_call_form').collapse('toggle')
  # alert('this holds things up long enough for me to see form is opening and immediately closing')
)

# handlers for the buttons
$('#phone_call_save').click(->
  $('#new_phone_call').submit()
  $('#phone_call_form').collapse('hide')
)
$('#phone_call_cancel').click(->  
  $('#phone_call_form').collapse('hide')
)

)
```

If I add the alert in there, I can see that the form is showing and hiding again immediately.

Using twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 and jQuery 1.9.1.  My code is included after bootstrap plugin, etc.
EDIT: Never mind.  The click event was attached to an icon.  It worked when I used a div, though no idea why??